# Tic Tac Toe Winning Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, tic-tac-toe

```
function checkWin(){
if (arro[0] === arro[1] === arro[2] === 1 || arro[3] === arro[4] === arro[5] === 1 || arro[6] === arro[7] === arro[8] === 1 || arro[0] === arro[4] === arro[8] === 1 || arro[2] === arro[4] === arro[6] === 1 || arro[0] === arro[3] === arro[6] === 1 || arro[1] === arro[4] === arro[7] === 1 || arro[2] === arro[5] === arro[8] === 1) {
    console.log("O Won");
    return "O";
}
else if (arrx[0] === arrx[1] === arrx[2] === 1 || arrx[3] === arrx[4] === arrx[5] === 1 || arrx[6] === arrx[7] === arrx[8] === 1 || arrx[0] === arrx[4] === arrx[8] === 1 || arrx[2] === arrx[4] === arrx[6] === 1 || arrx[0] === arrx[3] === arrx[6] === 1 || arrx[1] === arrx[4] === arrx[7] === 1 || arrx[2] === arrx[5] === arrx[8] === 1){
    console.log("X Won");
    return "X";
}
else
    return "notwin"; }
```

Here, the arro is the matrix for O and  the arrx is the array for X.
Running this in the console returns notwin everytime. Some help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You need to debug it. Evidently there's a problem with your logic in the condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine condition checks like that. When you do `a === b === c`, what you're doing is comparing the result value of the `a === b` expression (which will be `true` [if they're the same] or `false` [if not]) with the value of `c`.

Instead, you need to combine them with `&&`, e.g. `a === b && b === c`.

E.g.:

```
function checkWin() {
    if ((arro[0] === arro[1] && arro[1] === arro[2]) ||
        (arro[3] === arro[4] && arro[4] === arro[5]) ||
        /*...and so on...*/
       ) {
        console.log("O Won");
        return "O";
    }
    // ...
```

---

Side note: If you `return` from the block attached to the `if`, there's no need for the `else` prior to the next `if`. It's harmless, but pointless.